# Storing Code Signing Certificate

Tags: azure-devops, azure, azure-pipelines

I own a public and open-source Windows Forms/C# application in a Github repo that I want to start code signing with my certificate through Azure Pipelines CI.  I have set up my pipeline and it is building fine, the next step is to integrate automatic code signing, which until this point I have been doing manually. I have taken the following steps:

- Certificate has been added to Secure File storage
- Code Signing Extension Installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stefankert.codesigning
- Task variables have been created and marked as secret

After adding a task, the YML generating is:

```
- task: codesigning@2
  inputs:
    secureFileId: '$(certName)'
    signCertPassword: '$(certPass)'
    files: '**/*.exe'
    timeServer: 'http://timestamp.digicert.com'
    hashingAlgorithm: 'SHA256'
```

So, saving this, it is obviously going to update my **azure-pipelines.yml** in my repository. Is it possible to perform code signing in Azure Pipelines without exposing any information in the repository?  Is this considered best practice for code-signing in Azure Pipelines?

Comment: Hey - incidentally, it would be worth posting how many users download your application as this materially affects the risk assessment; i.e. if you get 100,000 downloads a month then your application is a might greater target of attacks.  If You get much less than that it's probably not enough of a target for an attacker to try and compromise your pipeline.  I really like this question because you are demonstrating two good practices merged together, those being code signing and CI/CD - well done.

Comment: @RichardSlater My application has typically less than 100 downloads per month, it is not that popular of a repository, but I wish to put the security of my project and userbase first and foremost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see you have done everything correctly, you have stored both the certificate material (i.e. the PFX) and the password for the PFX in a secure location that presumably no one else can access.  Assuming you don't give anyone else permissions on your Azure tenant and you don't blindly accept pull requests that change `azure-pipelines.yml` then you are in a good place.

If you are feeling paranoid, then you could create a second pipeline using a private repository that is triggered when the previous pipeline completes successfully.  However, IMHO, I would carefully consider the risk you are exposing yourself to against the complexity and fragility of trying to tie two pipelines together.

Comment: Thank you, I have determined I will add the code signing process to **azure-pipelines.yml** for now. I couldn't see how this would pose any risk given I alone manage the project but my paranoia probably comes from my day job in secure software development.